# How do I set up an OpenGL/C++ project with GLM?

Tags: c++, opengl, wavefront, .lib

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 for an OpenGL/C++ project and now I need to work with the [GLM library](http://devernay.free.fr/hacks/glm/).

I've downloaded the library and extracted it in my project folder. Then I set [addictional directories] from the properties of the project but it keeps giving me:

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glm.lib'
```

But there is not a glm.lib in the .zip on the website. Here are the "includes" in my main:

```
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "imageLoader.h
#include "..\glm-0.3.2\glm\glm.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

The website you linked only provides sources for the library. You will have to build it yourself to use it.

The source provides a Makefile.am to build the library with autotools but since you are using Visual Studio, it might be a little tricky to build it this way. On the other hand, this library is really small - only ten source files or so. It will probably be easier for you to just add these sources to you current VS project and build them with the default VSC++ compilation tools.

Also, there is a more common C++ library related to Opengl with the same name.  The one you are trying to use seems to load wavefront obj files. The GLM I know is a helper 3D math library with GLSL syntax ([GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net)).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Visual Studio 2017 I suggest following:

1. I suppose you have at least one toolkit, such as GLFW, freeGLUT, SDL, in folder C:\OpenGL\ and it is set up in an empty project.
2. Go to https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/index.html and download *glm*.
3. Drag it (or copy and paste) from the window is downloaded into folder C:\OpenGL. Now in folder OpenGL you have *glm* and at least one toolkit.
4. Go to V.S. > Solution Explorer > right click the project's name > click Properties > Open the C/C++ drop-down menu > General > Additional Include Directories > Click the down arrow at the right of the field > Edit... .
5. In *Additional Include Directories* window, click the first icon, copy C:\OpenGL\glm and paste in text box.
6. Click [OK] in *Additional Include Directories* window.
7. In the *Linker* drop-down menu, click *Input*. Click the *Additional Dependencies* entry and then the down arrow at the right of the field. Select *Edit* in the drop-down menu. Copy *opengl32.lib* and paste on the top-most text box in *Additional Dependencies* window. Click [OK] in *Additional Dependencies* window.
8. Click [Apply] and [OK] in the *Project Property Pages* window.

That's all. Regards.

Comment: OP was talking about GLM the [OBJ loader](http://devernay.free.fr/hacks/glm/), not the math library.